# Java interface with wildcard?

Tags: java

I need to write an interface which is going to be used in at least two different implementations such in the following example:

```
public interface AsdDAO{
    public Set<_What_?> getEntities();
}

public class AsdPlayerDao implements AsdDAO{
   public Set<Player> getEntities();
}

public class AsdPartnerDao implements AsdDAO{
   public Set<Partner> getEntities();
}
```

Such classes are going to be used in order to retrieve the collection of entities like the followoing:

```
@Autowired
AsdPartnerDao dao;

public void method(){
    Set<Partner> partners = dao.getEntities();
    //Some other stuff
}
```

Is it possible to use wildcards here like `public Set<?> getEntities();`. My question is in fact how to write the interface is the best way?

Comment: Did you try `public interface <T> AsdDAO{
    public Set<T> getEntities();
}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want

```
public interface AsdDAO<T>{
    public Set<T> getEntities();
}

public class AsdPlayerDao implements AsdDAO<Player>{
   public Set<Player> getEntities();
}

public class AsdPartnerDao implements AsdDAO<Player>{
   public Set<Partner> getEntities();
}
```

It is also possible to constrain the type, for example

```
public interface AsdDAO<T extends SomeInterfaceYouHave>{
```

Answer (score 0):

If the entities don't implement a common interface:

`public interface AsdDAO{
    public Set<?> getEntities();
}`

If they do:

`public interface AsdDAO{
    public Set<? extends YourInterface> getEntities();
}`

Comment: Using `?` makes this pretty useless.

Comment: Well, try using it. See how much you can do with these sets of unknown type.

Comment: @Thilo Well, I could cast it explcitcly to an apropriate type.

Comment: @St.Antario Avoid using wildcards in return types. It is confusing towards the caller of your method. (Effective Java 2nd edition) If you want the data structure to be unmodifiable, then wrap it with `Collections.unmodifiableXxx(...)`. Thilo is right. Think about what the added value is of using a wildcard here.

Comment: How do you know the appropriate type? Do `instanceof AsdPlayerDao`, `instanceof AsdPartnerDao` ...

Comment: In his code, seems that they don't use the daos by contract interface but concrete types, then it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Thilo Ok, so I could use wildcard here, but I shouldn't, correct?

Comment: Use a wildcard when you don't care about the type. But that is not what you want here, is it? It comes with a lot of limitations. For example, you cannot add anything to a `Set<?>`.